# How to make an executable jar or .app from a Swing application created in Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I have a typical swing application written in Netbeans. I followed the tutorial and whatnot, but now I am stuck trying to bundle this app into a .app file.

The problem seems to be that the jar file and its library directory (both of which I find in the dist folder) cannot be separated. When following the typical appbundler instructions, a non-executable .app file is created.

Does anyone have any suggestions? If .app is too high of a bar, can I somehow bundle the lib and the jar into a single executable jar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make an executable jar file from JarSplice I think.
http://ninjacave.com/jarsplice

Comment: Hi any alternatives to jarsplice in 2020? jarsplice 0.4 complains of zip END header not found

Answer (score 1):

don't know about the .app part but look at [jarjar](https://code.google.com/p/jarjar/) for embedding libraries in you jar and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html) for executable jars.

Answer (score 0):

To create an application bundle (.app) for Mac all you have to do is modify the build.xml file and use ant for the app bundler. There's a really helpful guide on the Oracle website:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html

It transfers all your dependencies (lib folder) to the contents of the app package, so it's executable by itself.